# Can you identify these two SMD components?

Tags: capacitor, surface-mount, damage

A couple of components get knocked off by some loose elements during the shipping of some equipment. I'd like to identify the elements and solder in some replacement.

[image]

My guesses:

- left one is a 270uF 16 V aluminium capacitor
- right one is a 470 ohm resistor (or is it an inductor)

Please confirm or correct me.

Comment: Questiona about places to order components are closed.

Comment: *...or is it an impedance* "an impedance" is not a component and the fact that it is **expensive equipment** means that **you** should not be servicing it, have the manufacturer repair the equipment. What if you (try to) fix it and it still doesn't work (which is very likely, there might be damage you cannot see)? Then how do you prove that **your "repairs"** didn't cause the problems?

Comment: The price will likely go up, or even no-bid if the customer attempted repairs. Ask them before proceeding (and I think I know what the answer will be).

Answer (score 13):

> during the shipping of some **extremely expensive equipment**.

You show a tantalum capacitor that has a crack and an electrolytic that is dented. That's not only shipping damage.  Who knows what else is damaged?

Return the equipment, and hold the shipping company liable for damages.

Comment: +1, whatever knocked these off could have flexed the board and broken SMD ceramic caps or SMD resistors or BGAs which are impossible to detect visually

Comment: Or maybe it was badly packed, either way not OP's responsibility.

Comment: @Jeroen3 oh, so both of them are capacitors. Did I get the ratings right: 270 uF and 470 uF?

Comment: Stop messing, put it back together and get the shipper to get it repaired on their insurance.